# Returning the image of the LPMetadataProvider in a function in the LinkPresentation Framework in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to have a function return only the image of the LPLMetadataProvider().

```
let image = fetchRichLinkimage(url: urltofetch[0])
```

This is what i got sofar. I have an Url as input and UIImage as output of that function.
Inside the function it instantiates the LPMetadataProvider(), then calls the fetchingMetadata method to retrieve the metadata. Within the metadata.imageProvider it loads the UIImage and if that image exists it should get returned as the output of the function.
I am new to SwiftUI/Swift so i have trouble understanding how i can assign the result to the output of the function. If someone can tell me what to do that would be appreciated.

```
func fetchimage(url: String) -> UIImage {
    return UIImage(systemName: "paperplane")!
}

func fetchRichLinkimage(url: String) -> UIImage {
    let metadataProvider = LPMetadataProvider()
    guard let urlURL = URL(string: url) else {
        return UIImage(systemName: "paperplane")!
    }
    
    metadataProvider.startFetchingMetadata(for: urlURL) { (metadata, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }
        
        guard let imageProvider = metadata?.imageProvider else { return }
        
        imageProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (image, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }
            if let image = image as? UIImage {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    return self.image
                }
            } else {
                print("no image available")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot return an image directly from `fetchRichLinkimage` because `.startFetchingMetadata` is an *asynchronous* task.

Comment: oh i see. i guess this is what dont get. so how do i make the function wait for the asynchronous task to finish? i guess i need to wrap it in a closure?

Comment: Exactly. Or, I showed you in a previous answer how to set a @Published property on an ObservableObject when it is done.

Comment: k thanks your comment helped me get it to work in a main app. but i am trying to get it to work in a widgetextension. and there one can't publish values but has to pass them to a timeLineEntry. So i have this API call that fetches the URLs and then i want to fetch the image for each URL from that JSON result to populate an image array in the Model. ... if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on your comments reflecting the fact that this is for a widget:

The following is a *very minimal* example of loading the LPLinkMetadata and associated UIImage in a widget, using callbacks from the TimelineProvider:

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import LinkPresentation

class LPLoader {
    let metadataProvider = LPMetadataProvider()
    
    func loadImage(url: URL, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
        metadataProvider.startFetchingMetadata(for: url) { (metadata, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                assertionFailure("Error")
                return completion(nil)
            }
            guard let imageProvider = metadata?.imageProvider else {
                return completion(nil)
            }
            imageProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (image, error) in
                guard error == nil else {
                    // handle error
                    return completion(nil)
                }
                if let image = image as? UIImage {
                    // do something with image
                    return completion(image)
                } else {
                    print("no image available")
                    return completion(nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil")!)
    }
    
    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        return completion(SimpleEntry(date: Date(), image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil")!))
    }
    
    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        let loader = LPLoader()
        loader.loadImage(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!) { (image) in
            guard let image = image else {
                return completion(Timeline(entries: [], policy: .atEnd))
            }
            return completion(Timeline(entries: [.init(date: Date(), image: image)], policy: .atEnd))
        }
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let image: UIImage
}

struct TestWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: entry.image)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

`LPLoader` is a class that just has one function, which loads the metadata for a link and then fetches the image. Note that it currently doesn't have any error handling.

In the `TimelineProvider`, you provide the timeline by calling the `completion`, which allows you to do asynchronous tasks (which you can't do in the widget itself). Right now, the data flow is relatively simple because there's just one image getting fetched. If you were to make a timeline with multiple entries and had to wait for them to load separately, it would get more complicated. I'd look into using Combine to do the asynchronous tasks separately and calling a callback when they're all finished (probably outside the scope of this question, but worth posting another question if you need this feature and don't know how to implement it).

Once the metadata and image are loaded, the original `completion` method for the TimelineProvider is called. The entry itself just has a `Date` and the `UIImage` that's been loaded.

Comment: thanks your example works. i guess the real problem is how to get it to work with fetching the array of urls. inside the getTimeline i call a func getData that pulls JSON from an URL and returns the modelData which it passes to the Timeline inside the closure of that function call. I keep trying to process the array of urls using the LPLoader inside the closure of the getData function. it compiles but crashes with a non-descript error just displaying a bunch of numbers in debug.

Comment: No way to know unless you post some code to try. If you found this answer helpful, please consider upvoting even if you don't accept it.

Comment: Thx will Post some of my code and let you know.